# Issue Looping Json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having an issue looping through json.

In the below code the looped urls are out of order and the id in the alert is always 3. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
var urls = ["http://soundcloud.com/disclosuremusic/sets/the-face-ep-1", "http://soundcloud.com/skibsthekid/sets/the-pink-slip", "http://soundcloud.com/disclosuremusic/sets/the-face-ep-1"];

for (var i = 0, url; url = urls[i]; i++) {
        console.log(i);

    $.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key, function(playlist) {
        alert(i + playlist.title);
    });
}
```

Comment: for (var i = 0, url; url == urls[i]; i++) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(urls,function(key,value) {
        console.log(value);

    $.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + value + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key, function(playlist) {
        alert(i + playlist.title);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the id in the alert will always be 3 in your case - but because of javascript architecture.

The `$.getJSON()` method, which is a shorthand for `$.get({ format : 'JSON' })`, acts as following:

- hey javascript, could you please give me the JSON content of `url`?
- yes man, but I have some stuff to do, and I can't wait till the server answers - please tell me what you want me to perform with such data, and wrap it inside a function. Meanwhile I'll go on with the script because I need to fadeOut some divs;
- ok javascript, here it is: `function(playlist){ ... }`.

This means that your `function(playlist){ ... }` callbacks are executed way after the `for` loop finished - this is why `i` is always 3.

The solution? You need a **closure** to let your callback be aware of `i` at current iteration - the topic isn't brief so take the brilliant [John Resig's interactive lecture](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48) about.